# AVAudioPlayer stops automatically when app joins agora.io channel

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession, agora.io

I am adding sound when user clicks on call button/joinChanne(Agora) in my app.

```
    [self.agoraKit joinChannelByToken:self.userManager.agoraToken channelId:self.userManager.channelName info:nil uid:[self.userManager.UID integerValue] joinSuccess:^(NSString *channel, NSUInteger uid, NSInteger elapsed) {
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ringing-sound-jalebi" ofType:@"mp3"];
        NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
        self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:nil];
        self.audioPlayer.delegate = self;
       [self.audioPlayer play];
     }];
```

But I am getting "AVAudioSession.mm:997:-[AVAudioSession setActive:withOptions:error:]: Deactivating an audio session that has running I/O. All I/O should be stopped or paused prior to deactivating the audio session" error. Can someone please help me to solve this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the Agora SDK is automatically deactivating any existing AVAudioSessions when you join a call, to make sure you can hear the person you're in a call with. I would recommend playing the sound through Agora's [sound mixing API](https://docs.agora.io/en/Voice/audio_effect_mixing_apple?platform=iOS) instead.

```
// Plays an audio effect file.
int soundId = 1; // The sound ID of the audio effect file to be played.
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ringing-sound-jalebi" ofType:@"mp3"]; // The file path of the audio effect file.
int loopCount = 1; // The number of playback loops. -1 means an infinite loop.
double pitch = 1; // Sets the pitch of the audio effect.
double pan = 1; // Sets the spatial position of the audio effect. 0 means the effect shows ahead.
double gain = 100; // Sets the volume. The value ranges between 0 and 100. 100 is the original volume.
BOOL publish = true; // Sets whether to publish the audio effect.
[self.agoraKit playEffect:soundId filePath:path loopCount:loopCount pitch:pitch pan:pan gain:gain publish:publish];
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Now how do you stop the audio??

Comment: Call pauseEffect: or stopEffect: with the id of the effect you played.